# Method with in the event

Tags: javascript, html, widget

I have use the following code snippet to for handling on scroll event with in the plugin

```
  handleScroll: function () {

            var contentdiv = $(".gridcontent");
            scrollTop = contentdiv.scrollTop();
            var vScrollDist = Math.abs(scrollTop - prevScrollTop);
            if (vScrollDist) {
                vScrollDir = prevScrollTop < scrollTop ? 1 : -1;                
                prevScrollTop = scrollTop;


            }
        },

        test:function(){
        },
```

but i can not call the test method from the handlescroll method(event). Can you please look into this .Thanks in advance

Comment: Is handlescroll a callback ? How does it get invoked? Please give a complete picture on what are you trying to do.

Comment: The problem could be the execution context used by `handleScroll`, who is called it and how?

Comment: contentdiv.bind("scroll", this.handleScroll);  Here contentdiv is a Div element i have bind the scroll event to this div by using handlescroll method

Comment: since you are not utilizing the element in the handlescroll referring to `this`, you can try `contentdiv.bind("scroll", this.handleScroll.bind(this));` and inside the handleScroll invoke it as `this.test()` or use `contentdiv.bind("scroll", $.proxy(this.handleScroll, this))`

Answer (score 2):

Because you are trying to bind an event to a method in a class (on the prototype I assume) you are going to need to bind the method to `this` or it will refer to the global state. So when you add your listener do it as follows:

`contentdiv.bind("scroll", $.proxy(this.handleScroll, this)); //or use fn.bind`

So this will refer to your plugin instance and not the window.

Comment: You can use `$.proxy(this.handleScroll, this)` as well...  and no need to add shim